# How can I implement a Dynamic WHERE-Clause using only SQL? (I can't use any programming language string concatentaion)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause, rdbms

I am using **MySql** and I am not so into SQL and I have the following problem with a query parameters:

I have a query that have a single mandatory parameters and a set of optional parameters.

At the moment I implemented this situation in this way (but it seems to me wrong):

```
WHERE Localization.id = 2

AND(
    EnutriMessageDetails.crop_id = 2
    OR
    EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_id = 1
    OR
    EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_action_id = 1
    OR
    EnutriMessageDetails.user_type_id = 1
    OR
    EnutriMessageDetails.urgency_id = 1
    OR
    EnutriMessageDetails.provided_by_id = 1
    OR
    EnutriMessageDetails.cleared_by_id = 1
    )
```

of which the **Localization.id** is the single mandatory parameter and all the parameters into the **AND** (and connected with **OR** operator each other) are the optional parameters.

Ok the problem is that from what I know, maybe, I have to use something like a **Dynamic WHERE-Clause**, doing an example:

if only these parameters are specified (Localization.id, EnutriMessageDetails.crop_id, EnutriMessageDetails.crop_id) it is created the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE 
    Localization.id = 2
AND
    EnutriMessageDetails.crop_id = 2
AND
    EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_id = 1
```

And so on.

I know that it is very simple do it using a programming language using string concatenation but I can't do it in this specific case because my query run directly into a tool that take SQL and use this SQL to create an XML. It is impossible for me do any kind of string concatenation to dynamically build the WHERE clause using string concatenation.

So, exist a way to do it using only SQL?

Comment: who is asking for the optional parameters ? What I mean is who is calling the query and specify them ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in mssql with making a string from my Query and after that you can execute this string instead of query .
I had no Problem with this method.

```
EXEC ( 'SELECT * FROM mytable');

Go;
```

you can use a String variable or any string combination you like.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188332(v=sql.120).aspx

it seems that mysql has the same.....``